# VlcXamarin don't work

Tags: android, xamarin, vlc

I want to use github.com/martijn00/VlcXamarin. So I try to run Sample from github, because I want to see how this works, but this isn't work. I discovered that problem is this line:

```
mLibVLC = new LibVLCLibVLC();
```

Someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Fix what? What is the error? Do we need to guess?

Comment: Project build success, but when I try run program than is turn off. So I don't have any error and I don't know what I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to show video with it too, without success yet.
The issue isn't with LibVLCLibVLC, an app just crashes after this if you have breakpoints in your app.

Check this:
https://github.com/martijn00/VlcXamarin/issues/7

**UPDATE:**
I found that VLC itself isn't working on particular device. To test it I downloaded VLC player for Android and tried to play it. Results was the same as in the app